# A global database of email addresses

Tags: data-request, email

Does anyone know of an open database of email addresses and meta data on the owners (not personal information)?

The sort of data I'm looking for has more to do with spam scores, creation date and other indicators that will help me determine the credibility behind an email address.

Please note that I am not looking for names, age, sex and other similar personal information...

Comment: Pretty sure that would be considered a data breach.  Who would want their information in the _open_ like that. Too many hackers and spammers.

Comment: That was not actually what I was looking for, I'm going to rephrase my question.

Comment: Check through here http://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=email

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no free one.

Suppose someone gives you a list of 1 million email addresses with some metadata and says: "These are our registered users, I've anonymized the personal information, now check the accuracy of this data, in particular check if the email address is still valid". What can you do?

You can check against someone else's list. These persons, who have been curating this, faced the same problem as you do. But why should they keep this information up-to-date and share this information with anyone? This would be considered illegal in many countries.

The internet giants, which probably could resolve a large fraction of the entries on your list, won't give you this information. Their APIs do not make this information queryable, on purpose.

There isn't even a reliable way to check if a string that looks like an email address actually *is* a valid email address string.

You can validate it syntactically, w.r.t. the specification, e.g. if there is an "@" inside at the right place etc, but there is no 100% reliable way. See for instance this answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/78353.

Maybe shady commercial data providers (e.g. direct marketing firms) offer such a email address validation + usage stats service, but they are certainly not free.